# OOP Programming in a GUI Application

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, javafx

I'm new to object-oriented programming (VBA was my origin language) and I'm getting into Java now to get a clue about it.

My first console program was a small text adventure with some classes like `Enemies`, `Player`, `Items` etc. which really helped me getting into OOP.

Second application was a GUI calculator in `JavaFX`

I want to build another more complex GUI application like a *Task-Planner* with some more scenes and buttons etc.

I don't really get how to make use of classes and objects in such a project.

I'm tending to just write it down all way long like in this *example*:

```
public class FirstGUI extends Application {

    Scene scene1, scene2;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setTitle("My First JavaFX GUI");

        //Scene 1
        Label label1 = new Label("This is the first scene");
        Button button1 = new Button("Go to scene 2");
        button1.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(scene2));
        VBox layout1 = new VBox(20);
        layout1.getChildren().addAll(label1, button1);
        scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 300, 250);

        //Scene 2
        Label label2 = new Label("This is the second scene");
        Button button2 = new Button("Go to scene 1");
        button2.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(scene1));
        VBox layout2 = new VBox(20);
        layout2.getChildren().addAll(label2, button2);
        scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I plan much more scenes and different buttons. But breaking everything down I don't see where making `Classes` or `Object` will help me out. I feel like defining all my buttons, pictures, tables and stuff and throwing them into the layouts is my `natural` way to go here.

Am I thinking wrong? May someone help me if it's just the *"VBA mind"* which is tricking me?

Comment: While an interesting and important topic, this Question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Questions here must address a narrowly-focused programming problem with a specific solution. Wide-ranging discussions are off-topic. I suggest visiting http://www.JavaRanch.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I will take this as a more general question instead of just for javafx. One starting point might be to split you user interface into logical sections, and capsulate them into class.So you  might have classes that inherit from a container class and in the top level class you just compose those container classes and deal with the specifics inside of them. This would keep your top level class much cleaner.

This is, of course, just a very generic and just meant as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if this is going to help you but... First of all, classes are "templates" for creating similar objects. If you have a need for something like that in your program you should create such a template and use it for creating objects when needed. If not...well don't force it. :) Good thing about JavaFx is that you can use FXML to create your views and therefore power up your GUI abilities but also ease your code. Try it, it will help you.

Good luck :)